# SPA done with ASP.net Boilerplate free template, login only works IE11 if developer tool are open

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, asp.net-boilerplate

I experiencing an issue with IE11.

I created a SPA project with ASP.net Boilerplate selecting .NET Core 1.1
(https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates).

The application works in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

The issue is with IE11 on windows 7.
It does not want to log in, but if I open the developer tools it logs in with out any issue. Close developer tools and the login stops working.

Any help or suggestions shall be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem because of IE's caching. It caches ajax requests (sometimes even when dev tools are open). To prevent it, we disabled client side caching with HTTP headers.

- Upgrade to `Abp.*` packages to v2.2.1.
- Upgrade `abp-web-resources` and `abp-ng2-module` npm packages.

Then the issue should disappear.

Comment: Thank you very much. ASP.Net Boilerplate is an amazing product!